# Django distinct related querying

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I have two models:

**Model A** is an AbstractUserModel and Model B

```py
class ModelB:
    user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='modelsb')
    timestamp = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What I  want to find is how many users have *at least one* ModelB object created **at least in 3 of the 7 past days**.

So far, I have found a way to do it but I know for sure there is a better one and that is why I am posting this question.

I basically split the query into 2 parts.

**Part1:**
I added a foo method inside the User Model that checks if a user meets the above conditions

```py
def foo(self):
    past_limit = starting_date - timedelta(days=7)
    return self.modelsb.filter(timestamp__gte=past_limit).order_by('timestamp__day').distinct('timestamp__day').count() > 2
```

**Part 2**:
In the Custom User Manager, I find the users that have more than 2 modelsb objects in the last 7 days and iterate through them applying the **foo** method for each one of them.
By doing this I narrow down the iterations of the required for loop. (basically its a filter function but you get the point)

```py
def boo(self):
    past_limit = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)
    candidates = super().get_queryset().annotate(rc=Count('modelsb', filter=Q(modelsb__timestamp__gte=past_limit))).filter(rc__gt=2)
    return list(filter(lambda x: x.foo(), candidates))
```

However, I want to know if there is a more efficient way to do this, that is without the for loop.

Comment: What do you mean `ModelA` is an `AbstractUserModel`? You mean it's a concrete subclass of `AbstractUserModel` and is it `User` in your code? And please show your code of the user manager.

Comment: @dirkgroten Yeap, I mean my User model is inheriting from the AbstractUser Model

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional annotation.

I haven't been able to test this query, but something like this should work:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Count

past_limit = starting_date - timedelta(days=7)
users = User.objects.annotate(
                    modelsb_in_last_seven_days=Count('modelsb__timestap__day', 
                        filter=Q(modelsb__timestamp__gte=past_limit), 
                        distinct=True))
            .filter(modelsb_in_last_seven_days__gte = 3)
```

**EDIT:**

This solution did not work, because the distinct option does specify what field makes an entry distinct.

I did some experimenting on my own Django instance, and found a way to make this work using SubQuery. The way this works is that we generate a subquery where we make the distinction ourself.

```
counted_modelb = ModelB.objects
    .filter(user=OuterRef('pk'), timestamp__gte=past_limit)
    .values('timestamp__day')
    .distinct()
    .annotate(count=Count('timestamp__day'))
    .values('count')

query = User.objects
    .annotate(modelsb_in_last_seven_days=Subquery(counted_modelb, output_field=IntegerField()))
    .filter(modelsb_in_last_seven_days__gt = 2)
```

This annotates each row in the queryset with the count of all distinct days in modelb for the user, with a date greater than the selected day.

In the subquery I use `values('timestamp__day')` to make sure I can do `distinct()` (Because a combination of `distinct('timestamp__day')` and `annotate()` is unsupported.)

Comment: That was my first thought too and I tried it. However it seems that distinct is not working correctly. I have created some dummy data, with 6 modelB objects in 5 different days. Running the above query gives modelsb_in_last_seven_days=6 instead of 5 for some reason I cannot understand.

Comment: It's possible the distinct option on Count gets all distinct entries by id, which is not what you want here. Let me check the source real quick to verify.

Comment: My assumption was correct, distinct just adds a DISTINCT keyword to the COUNT aggregation in the SQL query, but I did find a possible way to make it work. I'll update my answer.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the effort you put in this. I keep getting this error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` when running the User annotation. Have you encountered this?